# How can I see the full stacktrace in Android?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, stack-overflow, stack-trace

I'm using intelliJ. My problem is the "... 8 more" as seen at the bottom of the stacktrace. I need to know those 8 more lines. What is causing this? How can I show all lines????

```
06-25 00:02:39.459: ERROR/System(4065): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
06-25 00:02:39.459: ERROR/System(4065): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
        at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:121)
        at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:91)
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:80)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:118)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:142)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
        at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
        at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing a deliberate optimization.  The 8 lines are the same as the last 8 lines in the stack trace just preceding it.

Comment: There are no references to any classes in my app. I believe they are hidden in those 8 lines. Why is the stacktrace not originating my app?

Comment: No, I've just done some Googling and my error is caused by some file not being closed properly somewhere. I will bound in on the issue using manual debugging and report my findings shortly. thanks!

Comment: I have 3 services, but I am not calling startActivity from any of them...how can I bound in on this issue given I have no idea how to reproduce it??

Comment: Finalizers are run outside your own code.  The actual object with the finalizer is allocated elsewhere and not properly closed.  It looks like a FileInputStream object - do you have any of these in your code?